# Is there any support for Esperanto in LaTeX?

Tags: packages, languages, esperanto

Is Esperanto supported by LaTeX? And, if so, are there any required packages?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I run latex (TeX Live 2012 default installation) it reports that it includes Esperanto hyphenation patterns in its default format. `babel` has an `esperanto` option so

```
\usepackage[esperanto]{babel}
```

should make fixed texts like "Chapter" come out as "{\^C}apitro"

Comment: I'm not sure I like `babel` making `^` an active character (such that you can use it as a shorthand for the letters ĉ, ĝ, ĥ, ĵ, ŝ and ŭ) though. For example that should mean you can't use it together with `breqn` (not that I have tried though)

Comment: @kahen -- with `\^C`, `^` isn't an active character; it's just an ordinary text circumflex accent.  shouldn't affect `breqn` or any other math package at all.

Comment: @barbarabeeton you misunderstand. `\usepackage[esperanto]{babel}` makes it such that you can type `^c` to get a `ĉ` - which obviously requires `^` to be active.

Comment: @kahen babel has mechanisms for turning shorthands on and off so if there is a clash (and it isn't clear there should be) you could turn that feature off globally or locally for math environments.

Comment: @kahen You can disable the shorthand (`\shorthandoff{^}`) and use Unicode characters for input.

Comment: @david-carlisle How _would you turn it off just for math enviroments?

Comment: \everymath{\shorthandoff{^}} might work (and same with \everydisplay) but in the case of breqn it is already redefining almost everything in math expressions anyway so I'd probably just add to that.